# How to send returned data in ajax to php in the same file?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

After AJAX call, I got data in AJAXwith JSON format. Now I want to send that data to foreach loop in the same blade file of laravel.

*** here is ajax with data returned from the controller of laravel in json format***

```js
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.category').click(function(){
                var id= "";
                id= $(this).val();
                    console.log(id);
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"browse-events",
                        method: "GET",
                        data:{id:id},
                        success:function(reponseData){
                            console.log(responseData);
                        },
                        error:function(){
                            console.log('Error in receiving data');
                        }
                    });  
            });
        });
    </script>
```

*** This is foreach loop in php where returned data of ajax must be looped***

```php
            @foreach ($responseData as $data)
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <h6>{{$data->name}}</h6>
                        <p >{{$data->data_id}} </p>
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

here ***reponseData*** in ajax call has returned data in Json format. Now i need to send the data to foreach loop of php in the same blade.php file of laravel. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to send ajax/json data to the blade foreach loop.
    Blade processes php based arrays when the page is rendered, while ajax loads data when the page is already loaded.

```
The solution here would be to place the data with a javascript for loop:
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.category').click(function(){
                var id= "";
                id= $(this).val();
                    console.log(id);
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"browse-events",
                        method: "GET",
                        data:{id:id},
                        success:function(reponseData){
                            let parentObject = $('#parentObject'); //The object where all divs are in
                            responseData.forEach((data) => {
                                parentObject.append('
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                        <h6>'+ data.name +'</h6>
                                        <p>'+ data.data_id +' </p>
                                    </div>
                                ');
                            })
                        },
                        error:function(){
                            console.log('Error in receiving data');
                        }
                    });  
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

What you could do:

1. Either use React, Vue.js or Angular
2. Create the HTML elements after received the response and insert them by JS
3. Return the content already rendered (not recommended) and simply insert it in the view
4. Simply reload the page with the query parameter `id` and render the page accordingly