# How do I apply the data I received as AJAX from my label to my blade template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I used Ajax to get JSON's data from the controller. However, I don't know how to forward the data I received to the foreach statement of the blade template in the table tag.

Ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '{{route('translation.recodes')}}',
        type: 'post',
        data: {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data); // get controller data -> $translationRecords

        }, error: function () {
            alert("error!!!!");
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    @if($translationRecords)
       @foreach($translationRecords as $translationRecord)                            
           <tr>
              <td id="recodeValue{{ $translationRecord->id }}" style="display:none">{{ $translationRecord->id }}</td>
              <td>{{ $translationRecord->korean }}</td>    
              <td>{{ $translationRecord->japanese }}</td>
              <td><button id="recodeRemoveBtn{{ $translationRecord->id }}" type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right">삭제</button></td>                      
          </tr>
       @endforeach
    @endif
</table>
```

My prediction is that I'm thinking about using the jQuery to create dynamically in the table tags, but I don't know how to return the data from the controller either.

Comment: maybe not directly related, but this package for Laravel could help: https://github.com/freshbitsweb/laratables - usually you push your data to your table inside the .ajax function, take a look at this article: http://anytch.com/populate-table-jquery-ajax-laravel-5-x-4-steps/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply give an id to the table body and use template literals

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="transRecords">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

and then in your ajax function use Template Literals ``

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '{{route('translation.recodes')}}',
    type: 'post',
    data: {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
    success: function (data) {
        data.forEach((rec)=>{
        document.querySelector('#transRecords').innerHTML +=
        `
         <tr>
             <td id="recodeValue-${rec.id}" style="display:none">${rec.id}</td>
             <td>${rec.korean}</td>
             <td>${rec.japanese}</td>
             <td><button id="recodeRemoveBtn-${rec.id}" type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right">삭제</button></td>
        </tr>

        `
     })

    }, error: function () {
        alert("error!!!!");
    }
});
```

Comment: I have one more question: The code above adds a table every time I click "translationRecodeBtn," and I click "translationRecodeBtn" and I want it to last only once.
A table is now being created in the same situation as 1+N.

Comment: you want to remove the previous data? its simple, you can empty the table everytime you send a ajax request, let me know if thats what you want, i'll update the code

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you for all the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by doing something this. 
data[i] depends on how you are sending your data from the controller.

```js
$.ajax({
        url: '{{route('translation.recodes')}}',
        type: 'post',
        data: {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data); // get controller data -> $translationRecords
            $('#datatable tr').not(':first').not(':last').remove();
            var html = '';
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                html += '<tr>'+
                            '<td '+id="recodeValue'+data[i].id+'" style="display:none"+'>' + data[i].id + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].korean + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].japanese + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + data[i].var4 + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';
                }   
            $('#datatable tr').first().after(html);

        }, error: function () {
            alert("error!!!!");
        }
    });
```

```html
<table id="datatable">
</table>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError. An error is occurring. What is this?

Comment: @박보근 I have not code to fetch data from server, so its causing problem

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer for you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56426854/how-to-send-returned-data-in-ajax-to-php-in-the-same-file/56426969#56426969)
You can't.

What you could do:

1. Either use React, Vue.js or Angular
2. Create the HTML elements after received the response and insert them by JS
3. Return the content already rendered (not recommended) and simply insert it in the view
4. Simply reload the page with the query parameter `id` and render the page accordingly